# Configure SSH to read HostName for a Host from a file

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have the following host definition in my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host testbox
  User abc
  Port 12345
  HostKeyAlias=hello
  HostName 123.123.123.123
```

The problem is, this host changes IP all the time. The IP is refreshed and stored in this text file `~/ip.txt` as it's contents.

Is there a way to configure SSH such that when I run

```
ssh testbox
```

I automatically connect to the newest IP read from `~/ip.txt`?

(I would prefer not to use dynamic DNS if possible.)

Comment: Instead of witing to ip.txt, you could change your /etc/hosts file and ssh by hostname.

Comment: @stark Thanks for responding, but would prefer a solution that doesn't require root privileges.

Comment: @Jim: How do you receive new IP address? Instead of storing it in  `~/ip.txt` you could edit ~/.ssh/config instead.

Answer (score 8):

If your `~/ip.txt` can be made to contain

```
hostname 1.2.3.4
```

then you can

```
include ~/ip.txt
```

at the appropriate place in the `~/.ssh/config`.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you could use `ProxyCommand` like that:

```
Host test
Port 12345
ProxyCommand ssh -p %p "$(cat ~/ip.txt)" nc localhost %p
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Comment: This looks promising. But it's not working. 

I tried:
```
Host testbox
  User abc
  Port 12345
  ProxyCommand ssh "$(cat ~/ip.txt)" nc localhost %p
```
StrictHostKeyChecking makes no difference in whether it works or not. I tried using the IP directly instead of the $(), in case it was something wrong with the cat part and it doesn't work either. 
Can you explain the nc localhost %p part?

Comment: @Jim: see updated answer. `nc` is used to forward SSH traffic as explained at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts. Notice that it has to be installed on the server.

Comment: I needed to add %r to the command as well in order to use the right username. But it's still not working: "Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host" This error occurs even if I use "ForwardX11 no"

Comment: @Jim: can you try `ProxyCommand ssh -l %r -p %p "$(cat ~/ip.txt)" nc localhost 22`?

Comment: This works! A couple of questions: 1) I don't think I need StrictHostKeyChecking=no if I use HostKeyAlias? 2) Why port 22 specifically? I also tried a different port and it didn't work.

Comment: 1. Yes, you can use HostKeyAlias if you always set it before
connecting. 2. I really don't know, some firewall settings probably. I
can reproduce it on my Hostgator shared hosting that I connect to with
port 2222 with `nc localhost 2222 -v`: `nc: connect to localhost port
2222 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out nc: connect to localhost port
2222 (tcp) failed: Network is unreachable` but I see
`SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3` with `nc localhost 22`. It's very possible you
can actually use the default port 22 to connect to the server.

Comment: Does this imply a solution to [my question from 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55579583/241211)? I tried a cursory adaptation of your code, but my attempt didn't work.